# How should a selenium c# test be written?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I wanted to ask *what is the proper way to write a selenium **C# tes**t*?.

1. Should The test be written as a unit test or
2. As a console app

I have done both ways, but I wanted to know how the real world does it.

Thanks!

Comment: unit tests, so you can run all tests in parallel using different instances of the driver and evaluate asserts

Comment: @derloopkat, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write as Unit Tests. With the help of NUnit.